# I am not able to install any package using npm install

Tags: angular, npm-install

I am trying to start a new angularJS2 project using visual studio but i am not able to install any packages using npm command, i get the following error when i try to run the

[image]

> npm install command in my package manager console

I tried clearing the console, using

> npm cache clean

in the package manager console, still i am getting the error, I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and have the latest Typescript 2.0. I am in the proxy network. Any help on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: node js installed ?

Comment: yes i have installed node.js

Comment: try npm install -g Jquery to check if this works

Comment: i get a proxy or bad network network setting error

Comment: so that mean you ar enot able to reach to packages I think you network is issue . Are yoy able to browse npm website ? https://www.npmjs.com/ .

Comment: yes i am able to browse the site as well as ping it